# How to see in microsoft dynamics navision 2009 number of table

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I am using microsoft dynamics navision 2009. And I am using code unit. But if I press f5 on a function, for example this:

```
lRecStatus.SETRANGE("Change Status",lRecStatus."Change Status"::Released);
```

So I press f5 on: lRecStatus and then I hit f5 and then I see this:

See image. But how to know witch table it is then?

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find all of the variable decelerations in one of two places, global or local, this includes the reference to the table.

From the [C/AL Editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh168255(v=nav.70).aspx) you can access these under the view menu (Beeld for you I think).

[image]

[C/AL Globals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh165504(v=nav.70).aspx) will be available for the whole object

This will open directly to the variables tab, and you can see the type and subtype there.

[C/AL Locals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh166740(v=nav.70).aspx) will be available for just the function, so you will want to be in the same procedure for the variable you are looking for.

There are three places a local variable being used can be found.

- Parameters: These are passed to and from the function
- Return Value: this is a basic data type used to return from the function
- Variables:  this are variables local in scope to that specific
  function